# What's a cross-browser compatible way to right-align child divs and make the parent div get its width from the children?

Tags: css, iis, iis-6

I have a bunch of child `<div>`'s of variable width, which I want to right-align within a parent .  I also want the parent `<div>` to be no wider than it needs to be to contain the children. (I don't know in advance how wide the children will be -- they'll contain dynamically generated content.)

Here's an example that works correctly in IE 8.0 but not in Firefox 3.5 (child `<div>`'s aren't right-aligned):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #parentDiv{float:left; text-align:right; background-color: gray;}
      .childDiv{clear:both; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parentDiv"> 
      <div class="childDiv" style="width: 25px">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="childDiv" style="width: 50px">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="childDiv" style="width: 100px">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I add `float:right` to the childDiv's CSS, then it works in Firefox 3.5 but not in IE 8.0 (parentDiv's width is no longer determined from the width of its children).

Is there a way I can get the desired behavior in all major browsers?

UPDATE: Apparently the adding float:right to the child divs only produces the error in IE when I'm hosting the page in my IIS localhost.  (Which is what I was originally doing.)  Perhaps this is an issue with some IIS setting?  I'm running IIS 6.0

UPDATE #2: So it turns out IIS 6 was causing the page to load in IE7 Standards mode.  So the above code (with `float:right` added to the child divs) works for IE8 and Firefox, but apparently not for IE7.

I guess that makes the question: Is there a simple way to make this work in IE7?  (Besides just using a conditional comment or CSS hack to load a different stylesheet in IE7, I mean.)

Comment: ... so you want/need the parent element's width to be determined/controlled by the width of the children?
So the parent should only be as wide as the widest child element, irrelevant of the width CSS properties applied to said child element... ?

Comment: Right.  In this example it looks like I can just apply "width: 100" to the parent, but for the real project I'm working on I have children being generated dynamically so I don't know in advance what their width will be.

Comment: Do you have any constraints about the _positioning_ of the parent? Making the parent float might help, depending on the constraints. Let me know and I'll post my full answer.

Comment: Wait, I'm an idiot. You _are_ floating it to the left. But I tried in IE8 and what you've got seems to work... ?

Comment: Yes, what I've posted above works correctly in IE8 but fails in Firefox3.5 (I haven't tried in other browsers).  In Firefox, the children aren't right-aligned (despite my use of `text-align:right` which is what gave this effect in IE).  I can fix it to work in Firefox by adding `float:right` to the children, but that causes it to break in IE (specifically, the parent no longer sizes to its children).

Comment: What do you mean by right align of the child div? you mean that the text inside them is right aligned?

Can you please provide more info about what you really want? maybe div's aren't the best way to solve the problem

Comment: Not the text inside them . . .  I want the right edge of each child div to be touching the right edge of the parent div. (I have given them a border in my example to help illustrate this.)

If you load the above html page in IE 8 you will see it looking just how I want it.  But then load it in Firefox and it doesn't look right.  Adding `float: right` to the children fixes it in Firefox, but then it no longer looks right in IE.

Comment: http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/1745/screenshot001ai.png

In chrome, IE 8 and firefox 3.5.7... It looks exactly the same to me and works...

CSS:
<style type="text/css">
      #parentDiv{float:left; text-align:right; background-color: gray;}
      .childDiv{clear:both; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white; float: right;}
    </style>

Comment: AlfaTek, I don't understand how you're getting that to work in IE8.  When I use that CSS in IE I have the parent div extending across the full width of the window.  Is the rest of your page the same as mine, including `!DOCTYPE`?

Comment: After further investigation, adding float:right does seem to work, but *not* when I'm hosting the page in my IIS localhost (which is what I was originally doing).  How weird.

Answer (score 2):

*Edited Jan 21, 2010 @ 21:00 MST :* You need to float the parent div to the right. Originally I also floated the child divs right, but this caused trouble in IE7. If you have Firebug, take a look at [this test page](http://3roadsmedia.com/stackoverflow_test.html), which has the result you're after. I tested in Firefox 3.5, IE7, IE8, Chrome, and Safari 4.

Here is the relevant CSS and HTML (I added some margin/padding and background colors so you can more easily see the effect):

```
   <style type="text/css">
      #parent {
         margin:0;
         background:#ccc;
         float:right;
         padding:20px;
      }
      #parent div {
         background:#eee;
         margin:0 0 20px;
         text-align:right;
      }
   </style>

    ...

   <div id="parent">
      <div>Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sed euismod tortor.</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum, pharetra nec justo. In dapibus neque a libero cursus a laoreet nunc luctus.</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amdolor.</div>
   </div>
```

My guess as to why the original didn't work is that IE7 has a number of documented bugs ([see here](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/) for a list, which includes links to several float bugs). If you float both the parent and child elements to the right, you get the desired results in IE8 and other modern browsers, but in IE7 the parent's width won't collapse to the width of the widest child (enter mischievous bug).

IE7 behaves as expected if you float both the parent and child elements to the **left**, however (but this isn't what you were after).

Comment: This is bizarre . . . that test page works for me, but then if I copy it over to my localhost in IIS it exhibits the error I was seeing in IE . . . so maybe this was really an IIS issue all along.  I'll update the original question.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, copy and paste *just* the code I set up for you on the test page (i.e., don't paste it into something you already have). I've known IE to do funny stuff if there are things like HTML comments before the doctype declaration.

Comment: I've double checked, it's definitely the same code.  Actually, further investigation shows that IIS 6 is causing the page to load in IE7 Standards mode.  If I go into Dev Tools and switch Document Mode to "IE7 Standards", I see the same bug on your test page.  I'll update the question again with this new info.

Comment: Hey Tim, I'll check later tonight when I have access to a computer with IE7. Glad you found out what was causing the difference. The easiest solution is to use an IE7-specific CSS file, but I'll see if I can come up with a solution that works without it.

Comment: Hey Tim, I updated my answer with the...well, answer. I'm pretty sure this is what you're after. Take another look at the test link and let me know. The key difference was removing the **float:right** from the child divs, then setting their contents to align right.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I appreciate your efforts on this.  Your solution is close, but not quite right.  I want to make sure the inner divs themselves align to the right edge of the outer divs, not just align their text to the right.  Try fixing the width of one of the divs to be smaller than the others and you'll see it still aligns to the left of its container in your example.

For now, I'm just dealing with this by using a conditional comment to add a separate style sheet for IE 7 and earlier.  Not ideal, but so it goes.

That said, I appreciate your efforts on this.  I've marked your example as helpful.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Tim. My guess is that there is an IE bug that's preventing the cross-browser solution you're looking for. Thanks for the up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating all the child divs to the right, then adding a separate footer with width:%100 and clear:both?  I believe this will make IE properly scale the parent as it will have an element within it that is the proper width as well as in the document flow (floated objects are removed from the flow.)  You may require display:inline on the clear as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to fix my problem.  If I put `float:right` on the child divs then in IE the result I get is that the parent has the full width of the page, whereas I want his width to be only big enough to hold his children (as it was when the child divs weren't floating).  This problem persists even if I add another child div with the styles you suggest.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what programming language are you using to deliver the dynamic content?  And what kind of content is being fetched?  I only ask because in the case of images I can think of some tremendously extreme methods of accomplishing this by finding the image's size via script and using that within an inline style.  Just a thought and likely not the best method.

Comment: I'm working in ASP.Net 2.0, coding in C#.  The children are actually drop down lists with the choices being populated from the database.  The width of the drop downs ends up matching the width of the longest choice.  I could probably write a script to resize the parent div after the width of the content is determined, but it doesn't seem like this should be necessary (especially since I already know I can do it with CSS alone for either Firefox or IE, just not both at once).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: relative;` to the parent and `float: right;` to the children

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem.  `float: right` fixes it for Firefox, but causes it to break in IE (specifically, the width of the parent is now the full width of the page, not the width of the children).  Even after adding `position: relative` this problem persists in IE.

Comment: I've found that `float:right` only causes errors in IE when I'm hosting the page on my IIS localhost.  I've updated the original question to reflect that this is apparently an IIS issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: relative;` on the parent, and most importantly, you need to [clear those floats](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).